# Do i need to add google map api v2 for viewing map for particular location by Intent.Action_View with Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + formattedAddress))

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-api-3

This is my code:

```
Intent geoIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+formattedAddress));
startActivity(geoIntent);
```

I am trying to view specified address on map by clicking a map button in application but at run time. I am getting error as:

```
09-30 15:59:18.701: E/MapLocation(734): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=geo:0,0?q=india }
```

So tell me what should I do?

Comment: have you test on device or emulator ? if formattedAddress value "india" then your code is working fine.

Comment: I am checking in emulator nexus 4 device

Answer (score 0):

you can use google static map api and open it in browser
something like this :

Intent geoIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=37.400470,-122.072981&zoom=13&size=500x300&sensor=TRUE_OR_FALSE"));
startActivity(geoIntent);

Comment: Actually i want to use Uri.parse with "geo" but thanks for your reply @saber safavi